# Convert date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I know this has been asked like 100 times but I still don't get it and the given solutions don't get me anywhere.

Im trying to convert time into a comparable format with Pandas/Python. I used a db entries as data and currently I have trouble using time like this:

```
52   2017-08-04 12:26:56.348698
53   2017-08-04 12:28:22.961560
54   2017-08-04 12:34:20.299041
```

the goal is to use it as `year1` and `year2` to make a graph like:

```
def sns_compare(year1,year2):
    f, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, figsize=LARGE_FIGSIZE)
    for yr in range(int(year1),int(year2)):
        sns.distplot(tag2[str(yr)].dropna(), hist=False, kde=True, rug=False, bins=25)
sns_compare(year1,year2)
```

When I try to to it like this I get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2017-08-04 12:34:20.299041'`.

So currently I think about using Regex to manipulate the time fields but this cant be the way to go or at least I cant imagine. I tried all kind of suggestions from SO/GitHub but nothing really worked. I also don't know what the "optimal" time structure should look like. Is it `20170804123420299041` or something like `2017-08-04-12-34-20-299041`. I hope somebody can make this clear to me.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with converting year1 and year2 to ints?  Could you change your 'for' loop to be, 'for yr in [year1, year2]'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your data:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([("2017-08-04 12:26",56.348698),("2017-08-04 12:28",22.961560),("2017-08-04 12:34",20.299041)])
df.columns = ["date", "val"]
```

First, we convert to datetime, then we reduce `year1`, next we convert to days.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df["days"]=(df['date'] -datetime(year1,1,1)).dt.total_seconds()/86400.0
```

plot the data, and display only the days between `year1` and `year2`

```
plt.scatter(df["days"],df["val"])
plt.xlim((0,(year2-year1)*365))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)? Pandas and Seaborn should be able to handle dates fine, and you don't have to convert them to integers.